# using vs. typedef for std::vector::iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, using, stdvector

I am having a problem when using  the new C++11 `using` keyword. As far as I understand, it's an alias for `typedef`. But I cannot get it to compile. I want to define an alias for an iterator of a `std::vector`. If I use this everything works perfectly.

```
typedef std::vector<fix_point>::iterator inputIterator;
```

But if I try:

```
using std::vector<fix_point>::iterator = inputIterator;
```

The code doesn't compile with:

```
Error: 'std::vector<fix_point>' is not a namespace
using std::vector<fix_point>::iterator = inputIterator;
                            ^
```

Why doesn't this compile?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You just have it backwards:

```
using inputIterator = std::vector<fix_point>::iterator;
```

The alias syntax sort of mirrors the variable declaration syntax: the name you're introducing goes on the left side of the `=`.

Answer (score 9):

typedef is a specifier that may be mixed with other specifiers. Thus the following typedef declarations are equivalent.

```
typedef std::vector<int>::iterator inputIterator;
std::vector<int>::iterator typedef inputIterator;
```

Opposite to the typedef declaration the alias declaration has strict order of specifiers. According to the C++ Standard (7.1.3 The typedef specifier)

> A typedef-name can also be introduced by an alias-declaration. The
>   identifier following the using keyword becomes a typedef-name and the
>   optional attribute-specifier-seq following the identifier appertains
>   to that typedef-name. It has the same semantics as if it were
>   introduced by the typedef specifier. In particular, it does not define
>   a new type and it shall not appear in the type-id.

Thus you have to write

```
using inputIterator = std::vector<int>::iterator ;
```

Comment: @Barry It is me who sometimes used the second declaration.:)